# I'm getting the message Error: verb 'chmod' not recognized when trying to run a chmod command [MACOS]

Tags: macos, github, macos-sierra, chmod, twitch

This is what I'm trying to run in the terminal to grant executable rights for something I found on github. The steps I'm supposed to take are: "Browse to where you extracted the file and give it executable rights in the terminal". What am I doing wrong? I assumed chmod was a standard command. I'm also extremely new to using terminal.

Macs-MBP-2:~ REDACTED$ /Volumes/Backup\ Plus/Youtube/Raw\ Files/TwitchDownloaderCLI chmod +x TwitchDownloaderCLI
TwitchDownloaderCLI 1.51.1
Copyright (C) 2023 TwitchDownloaderCLI

ERROR(S):
Verb 'chmod' is not recognized.

--help       Display this help screen.

--version    Display version information.

Macs-MBP-2:~ REDACTED$

I have tried researching how to use chmod.
I have tried re introducing the file directory.
I have tried setting up the command in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you want to run:

```
cd /Volumes/Backup\ Plus/Youtube/Raw\ Files
```

to change directory (`cd` is 'change directory') to the location of the file.

Then run `chmod` on the file in the directory:

```
chmod +x TwitchDownloaderCLI
```

But it would appear that `TwitchDownloaderCLI` is already executable because the error message is the `TwitchDownloaderCLI` tool complaining that it doesn't understand the sub-command `chmod`.

Comment: Oh yea? Sorry, extremely new. But if it already has executable rights, why am I unable to use the downloader? Am I supposed to be setting up commands inside the actual TwitchDownloaderCLI file, or inside a regular terminal window? the command I'm attempting in the terminal is: ./TwitchDownloaderCLI videodownload --id <Vod ID here> -o out.mp4 (I've substituted the 'VOD ID here' part for an ID). but the terminal says: -bash: syntax error near unexpected token in reference to the VOD ID that I used.

Comment: I'm guessing this is the tool - [https://github.com/lay295/TwitchDownloader](https://github.com/lay295/TwitchDownloader). Is that correct? If your Vod Id were 12345, would you be using `./TwitchDownloaderCLI videodownload --id 12345 -o out.mp4` as the command?